# Getting a List of Dates from Apache Commons DBUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbutils

I am trying to get a list of dates from a table using Apache Commons DBUtils.
This kind of query works well with Strings and my own POJOs, but for some reason does not work on java.sql.Date's.

CALENDAR_DATE in PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS is a valid date field.

Query :

```
select CALENDAR_DATE TIME from PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS where CALENDAR_DATE between ? and ?
```

Java code

```
ResultSetHandler<List<java.sql.Date>> h = new BeanListHandler<>(java.sql.Date.class);
QueryRunner db = new QueryRunner(dataSource,true);
List<java.sql.Date> sqlDates = db.query(sql, h,new java.sql.Date(from.getTime()),new java.sql.Date(to.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to build your own ResultSetHandler. Maybe there is a simpler way, but I could not find one.

```
ResultSetHandler<List<java.sql.Date>> h = new ResultSetHandler<List<java.sql.Date>>() {

public List<java.sql.Date> handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
  List<java.sql.Date> result = new ArrayList<java.sql.Date>();
  while (rs.next()) {
     result.add(rs.getDate(1));
  }
  return result;
}
};

List<java.sql.Date> sqlDates = db.query(sql, h,new java.sql.Date(from.getTime()),new java.sql.Date(to.getTime()));
```